# How to Get the Id from angular app for Update and how to Get the Data from HTTP Post into the PHP file?

Tags: javascript, php, angular

I am trying to update and Add Data from my angular app to Server using PHP. 
I am Struck at how to give the URL Id from the angular app for update and how to get the values from Http POST into php for inserting into table. This is my code:

```
getEmployee(id : number){
                const eurl='http://localhost/Angular/UpdateEmployee?id='
                const url= `${eurl}${id}`
                return this.http.get(this.empurl)
                .map(response => response.json().data as Data)
                .catch(this.HandleError)

            }
```

This is my PHP for Update:

```
<?php 
$successreturn[]=array(
        "id"=>"any",
       "firstname"=>"any",
      "lastname"=>"any",
    "dateofbirth"=>"any",
    "city"=>"any",
    "gender"=>"any");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
$id=$_GET['id'];
$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="sandeepchetikam";
$dbase="mydb";
$conn=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbase);
if (!$conn) {
    echo "Connection Problem".mysqli_connect_error($conn);
}

$sql= "SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE id='$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $value=0;
if(!$result){
    echo "Connection Failed " .mysqli_connect_error($result);
 }
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $successreturn[$value]['id']=$row['id'];
         $successreturn[$value]['firstname']=$row['firstname'];
         $successreturn[$value]['lastname']=$row['lastname'];
         $successreturn[$value]['dateofbirth']=$row['dateofbirth'];
         $successreturn[$value]['city']=$row['city'];
         $successreturn[$value]['gender']=$row['gender'];
         $value++;

        };
echo json_encode($successreturn);


?>
```

Code for addEmployees:

```
addEmployees(data: Data): Observable<Data>{
                let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
                let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
                return this.http.post(this.empurl,data,options)
                        .map(this.extractData)
                        .catch(this.HandleError)
            }
```

I would like to know how to write the link for the getEmployee() function. 
And how to write PHP for addEmployees.

Comment: Feels like you have two separate questions here. I think I could answer the first one tho, but can't answer since I'm not sure about the second :P

Comment: And as comment, I think you would only have an employee with that unique id (???), so maybe consider returning an object instead of array.

Comment: I kept it the function which calls getEmployee in `ngOnInit` and the function is not getting called.
`OnInit(){  
  this.route.params
  .switchMap((params:Params)=> this.dataservice.getEmployee(+params['id']))
  .subscribe(data=> this.data = data)
  console.log(this.data);
 }`
I'm not getting any call in networks tab. I dont know whats wrong. I used InMemory and its working fine. Dont know whats wrong when i try it this way.

Comment: Getting any errors? Have you removed the InMemoryWebApi from your module? And I would use URLSearchParams instead in your GET request and make some changes to PHP too, to return an Object. I'm no expert in PHP, but when I do get request for one row in DB I return just one object.

Comment: Yes, I removed the InMemoryWebApi. The above code on ngOnInit is not calling the function in service. Can you tell me why? When the component loads a call should go to the Link right. I can't find any call on my networks tab. So I am getting an error FIrstname not defined in my template.

Comment: are you subscribing in your ngOnInit?

Comment: `this.route.params .switchMap((params:Params)=> this.dataservice.getEmployee(+params['id'])) .subscribe(data=> this.data = data) console.log(this.data); }`              Is this the right way to subscribe for the service??

Comment: Yes, that looks correct. Could you try and reproduce this issue in a plunker with some dummy JSON. It's much easier to help when we have code to debug :)

Comment: Only thing is that your console.log will be undefined, since it's outside the callback. It should be inside `subscribe`. But that doesn't affect why the http request isn't fired...